# Advice for updating old Swift Project

Tags: swift, xcode

I inherited a Swift 2 project that needs to be updated to Swift 4 or 5. I downloaded XCode 8.3.3 to try and go from Swift 2 to 3 and then Swift 3 to 4 using XCode 10.1. The version of XCode that will convert from Swift 2 to 3 won't run on Mojave. Is ther an alternative approach? I'm looking at >1000 errors currently.

Comment: There are 3 votes to close, 2 for "too broad" and one for "unclear what you're asking". Nonsense, this is a perfectly clear and precise question: "How do you migrate old versions of Swift?"

Comment: I agree. I'd guess over 40% - maybe "> 1000" won't easily migrate from Swift 2.x to Swift 3.x. That's the pain we all felt about *three* years ago. My guess is your best way to migrate something is (1) manually migrate it using Xcode 10 or (2) start from scratch with a new project.

Comment: You can try downloading old versions and running them in virtual machines, but that'll probably be more of a pain than it is to manually migrate it :/

Comment: Last comment, maybe more for @Alexander. Sorry, but **run**. Run away, fast. Swift 2 to Swift 3 conversion - something you simply *cannot* do with a version of Xcode 9+ - isn't easy. (Unless you have experience in Swift version *and* Xcode. But even then, depending on project size, it'll take days or weeks.) It sounds to me as though someone is testing you, as in *"I inherited a Swift 2 project...."* If you *really* need this gig and cannot run, then estimate BIG. And yeah, your best bet IMHO is to use Xcode 10, manually set the build to Swift 4 or preferable 5, and do it right.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. This software was written by a startup that folded back in 2016. The software was cool, but it was mothballed when the startup went sideways. I'm going to try and fight my way through it.

Comment: "but it was mothballed when the startup went sideways" -1 for using too many metaphors in one sentence. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an alternative approach

Not really. What you have discerned is right: to open the project at all, you need an older version of Xcode, but to run that, you need an older system.

I've faced this problem in the past. If you have an oldish computer, you can install an older system, and thus run an older version of Xcode, possibly on an external drive or extra partition, and thus migrate the project forwards step by step. If you don't have an oldish computer, you *might* be able to use a virtual machine, but it would probably be simpler to get hold of an oldish computer and keep it on hand just for this purpose. That's what I do.

Comment: [Wikipedia's Xcode page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) is a treasure trove of information about versions of Xcode, the versions of Mac OS X needed to run, and the versions of Swift included.  This will help you plan a path to upgrade your project a step at a time.